# React SignalR callback missing constants

Tags: reactjs, signalr, react-hooks

I am using React with react hooks and SignalR. I have some consts properties that are linked to input fields

```
const [name, setEmployeeName] = useState<string>('');
const [id, setEmployeeId] = useState<string>('');
const [project, setProjectName] = useState<string>('');
```

And following a chat tutorial setup the connection and subscriptions in useEffect like

```
useEffect(() => {

    // Set the initial SignalR Hub Connection.
    const createHubConnection = async () => {

        const hubConnect = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(`${url}/emp`)
            .build()
        try {
            await hubConnect.start()
            console.log('Connection successful!')

            hubConnect.on('update', (employee: Employee) => {
                if(id === employee.id) {
                     setEmployeeName(employee.name)
                     setProjectName(employee.project)
                 }
            })
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Error while establishing connection: ' + { err })
        }
        setHubConnection(hubConnect);
    }

    createHubConnection();

}, [])
```

So when I invoke the 'update' method from the server side and enter the implementation here, all those consts are missing and are ''.

So this `if(id === employee.id)` is always false.

For me it seems like I need to bind .this but I don't think we have this in React.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after further thinking I realised this was not a good approach. So i tweaked the subscription. Linked the input change to this method:

```
function onIdChange(_id: string) {
    if(_id !== id) {
        hubConnection!.off(`updateEmployee/${id}`)
        setEmployeeId(_id)

        hubConnection!.on(`updateEmployee/${_id}`, (employee: Employee) => {
            setEmployeeName(employee.name)
            setProjectName(employee.project)
        })
    }
}
```

So now from the server, whenever I want to invoke a method with the employeerId, I have already set a subscription and once I call it I no longer need to do the if statement.